# Caching in Django: Redis + Django & Varnish

Tags: python, django, caching, varnish

I've read up on some documentation and had a few questions.

I am aware we can use redis as a cache backend for Django. We can then use the decorators in Django's cache framework to cache certain views. I understand to this point but I've learned about a HTTP accelerator called Varnish.

How does Varnish work if used with redis + django cache? What is the difference between Varnish and Django + redis cache using in the in-built cache framework? Can these two things work side by side because having a web accelerator sounds really good actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varnish is a **caching HTTP reverse proxy**. It's always **in front** of your server. However Redis is a key-value store. So they are not located in the same level. For me, I use redis to store builded objects, result of DB queries, and varnish for static pages (Don't cache your dynamic content with Varnish this will cause a lot of trouble)